# /etc/apache2/httpd.conf Gone Missing?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu

Today I found my VPS provider physically rebooted the machine that hosts my VPS. I cannot start Apache again due to this error:

```
apache2: Syntax error on line 214 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Could not open configuration file /etc/apache2/httpd.conf: No such file or directory
Action 'start' failed.
```

Alas, doing ls /etc/apache2/httpd.conf indeed doesn't show the missing file.

I have no idea what went wrong. I have never touched this file at all. Apache used to work pretty much fine until that physical was done.

How do I fix this? I would just do "touch httpd.conf" in /etc/apache2, but obviously this file has something important and is not meant to be left blank.

Comment: Restore from your backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whew! After changing my google queries, I actually found [This StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11687125/my-httpd-conf-is-empty) asking about empty httpd.conf files. Reading the answers assured to me that I could just touch the file.

Now I have the file there (empty - like it's supposed to be) and got my site up and running again.

Still I have no idea of what caused this, but I'm glad I got it fixed.